# Communtiy rejecting seemingly valid edits

Tags: support

The following (partial)screenshot more or less states my question...

The question was edited by the OP who added the terminal output in an unreadable copy and paste.  It was subsequently edited by another user just as I was going to add the code blocks to make the output readable.  I, of course approved it as it seems to be a valid post that improves the question greatly.  The question needed one more review to be approved- the "Community" bot immediately rejects said edit....

While I could be wrong, I don't think the edit should have been rejected("Community" did not give a reason, I have to assume too trivial??).  So unless I am completely off base, I believe that the "Community" bot has been bitten by a bug???

.....or am I completely wrong and only adding code blocks is now considered too trivial an edit??

{edit} hmmm, so when I clicked back on the question window after posting this question, the "edit" button was show that there was an edit waiting....it wast the same edit(at least as far as I could tell) that was rejected by the community, by the same Editor.  So it would seem that the bug either resolved itself, or it is the same bug in a different form??....

[image: rejected??]

Comment: Can you post a link to the review page shown above?

Comment: @Seth , just curious, why would this be a support tag and not a bug tag?  (for future reference)

Comment: @TrailRider check the tag except/wiki ;)

Comment: @Braiam , I did check the description for the bug tag before I used it "...you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system..." as opposed to the support tag; "You need help with the use of one or more of the site's features".  It appeared to me to be "unexpected behaviour" as opposed to "me needing help using the site" hence the question- why `support` was the appropriate tag as opposed to `bug`

Comment: @TrailRider You didn't do anything wrong, but since this isn't actually a bug I retagged it. (the SE developers monitor the [meta-tag:bug] tag on all meta sites, just less work for them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two edits but I'm not quite sure what actually happened here. When the Community user steps in, it's usually just mirroring other behaviour.

- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/187827
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/187828 (3 minutes later)

In the second, the community account accepted the edit because Seth did. He edited the edit and said it was useful. The Community placed an accept vote in Seth's place.

For the first edit, I can't see any behaviour that happened in the same second that the Community user acted... It feels like it was too late for it to be an automated reject (because you'd had time to review it by then)... Perhaps it was because they were writing the second edit...? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I'm just guessing but after seeing both edits is probably that the user noticed another mistake and edited after TrailRider approved the edit, then community rejected the first edit... can be a possibility.

Comment: yeah, I think someone had it open and editing before - then submitted after seth approved

Comment: @Braiam  I would assume that you are correct, at least is seems valid. Not much else makes sense....  ---Oli, sorry I was not able to pass on the link, I went to bed not long after posting the question, I see you found it anyway, but it would have been easier for me to get it from my internet history.....